# CA Certificates Not Recognized

Tags: wget, certificates, ros

I've been trying to get CA Certs installed because I'm getting errors when trying to use `rosdep init` which makes calls to "raw.githubusercontent.com". If I do the same call with `wget` I'll get the same error:

```
ERROR: cannot verify raw.githubusercontent.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

I have installed ca-certificates. I also tried this on a fresh install and everything worked fine. However, I cannot reinstall on the machine I am on at the moment, is there a way to resolve this some other way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with `rosdep` but can you try to update your certificates with;

`sudo update-ca-certificates -f`

If that doesn't work and you sure `rosdep` is using `wget` can you try to add this line to your `~/.wgetrc`

`check_certificate = off`

It should ignore certificate errors afterwards. It can be GitHub issue so can't comment on that. I can wget files from `raw.githubusercontent.com` without any issues tho.

Comment: While this solves my wget issue it does not solve the overall problem with certificates. 

1. rosdep does not appear to use wget 
2. It is still a security concern to have the cert not verified for all wget calls

I was hoping to find a broader solution and was using wget as an example.

Comment: I can't repro your issue. I can `sudo rosdep init` also can `update rosdep`. Which `ca-certificates` version is installed on your system?

Comment: ```sudo dpkg -s ca-certificates | grep Version
Version: 20210119~20.04.1```

Comment: Hmm seems you are using up to date version. Have you tried reinstalling `ca-certificates`? If not can you try reinstalling with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`, after that can you confirm `DigiCert` certificates are located in `/etc/ssl/certs`. Here is a output from my system: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jcCG29xt6w/](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jcCG29xt6w/)

Comment: Yes I've tried that as well and see multiple certs with DigiCert in the directory.
```ls /etc/ssl/certs/ | grep DigiCert
DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
```

Comment: Can you try to wget with `--ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs` param?

Comment: Great! So that worked. Now is there a env setting that I have wrong that other services aren't looking there for certs?

Comment: Afaik there is no env var for that. `update-ca-certificates --fresh` should do the trick. You can try adding `ca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs` to your wgetrc in your home dir as well as in `/etc/wgetrc`. Maybe some app you've installed before broke something can you check it?

Answer (score 2):

In the end adding this env var to my `~.bashrc` file made the ROS calls work:

```
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```